# NSPrintOperation creates a blank page

Tags: nsview, nsprintoperation

I am not able to print in Cocoa using the service:
[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self] runOperation];
The print dialog gets launched but the preview is blank.
Please let me know what could be the issue?

I have a CGImage (iImageRef) which I want to print.
Here are the ways I tried:

1.

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iImageRef size:size];
NSView* printView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[printView setWantsLayer:YES];
printView.layer = [CALayer layer];
printView.layer.contents = image;
NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView];
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:YES];
[printOperation runOperation];
```

2. 

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iImageRef size:size];
NSView* printView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[printView setWantsLayer:YES];
printView.layer = [CALayer layer];
printView.layer.contents = image;
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[printInfo setTopMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setBottomMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setLeftMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setRightMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
[printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView printInfo:printInfo];
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:YES];
[printOperation runOperation];
```

Comment: Please tell us more about your view and post a [mre].

Comment: Hello @Willeke I've added the sample code. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Willeke, yes, it's similar to the link you shared. Creating NSImageView first, adding image to it and then assigning this NSImageView to NSView solved the issue.
Thanks a lot for your help!